# Open Multiple windows on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, window

This is how far I have gotten to. The form is just a simple checkbox with urls in each checkboxes value.
This works half the way. I can't manage to resize the windows neither in Chrome or Firefox.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(){

    $('#goTo input:checked').each(function(count){

        var goTo;
        var wWidth; 
        var wHeight;
        var windowSize;
        i = 25 * count;

        goTo = $(this).val();
        wWidth = $(window).width() - $(window).width() / 2;
        wHeight = $(window).height() - i;
        windowSize = "width="+wWidth+"height="+wHeight;

        window.open(goTo, 'title', windowSize);                 
    });


    return false;

});
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the other error with this - Only one window is opened even if there are 3 checkboxes checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `resizable=1` should do it:

```
window.open(goTo, 'title', windowSize + ',resizable=1');
```

But you also have an error in setting the `windowSize` - it's missing a `,`:

```
//       missing comma here ->
windowSize = "width="+wWidth+",height="+wHeight;
```

Comment: COMMAS! I forgot the freaking commas :). Thanks :) Any ideas on why the loop is broken ?